# Excel VBA - Unable to duplicate worksheet in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy

From a workbook, I am attempting to open another workbook, duplicate the master worksheet in that workbook and rename it. The problem being that no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work when I Copy the master sheet.

**Attempt One - Using the copy method.**

```
Sub individualStats()

  'Initialize
  Dim app As New Excel.Application
  app.Visible = False
  Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
  Set objWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add("S:\MH\Stats\Jordan Individual Stats.xlsm")

  'Test if Worksheet exists already
  Set wsTest = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  Set wsTest = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Worksheet")
  On Error GoTo 0 

  'If worksheet does not exist then duplicate Master and rename
  If wsTest Is Nothing Then

    objWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Copy After:=objWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.count) 
    ' ^ This is the line I get the error on.
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Test Worksheet"

  End If 

  'Save and close workbook.
  app.DisplayAlerts = False

  objWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="S:\MH\Stats\Jordan Individual Stats.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
  app.Quit
  Set app = Nothing

  app.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I have marked the line I get the error on. The error is
"Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range."

**Attempt Two - Calling a Macro from the Workbook**

Inside of the "Jordan Individual Stats.xlsm" workbook I have created this Macro.

```
Sub duplicateMaster()
   Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Test Worksheet"

End Sub
```

This sub works completely fine if I run it within that workbook.

But when I try to call this module from the original workbook it doesn't work.

```
...
If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    Application.Run ("'S:\MH\Stats\Jordan Individual Stats.xlsm'!duplicateMaster")
End If 
...
```

The error comes up on the line in the duplicateMaster module on the line         "Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)".

The error is the same "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well there are only two possible failures, either sheet named "Master" does not exist, of the index `Worksheets.Count` doesn't exist. The latter seems unlikely.  Break that statement in to two lines, using debug.print or other technique and examine whic failure mode you're having...

Comment: For example, use: `Debug.Print objWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Name` and see if that raises an error.

Comment: Also try doing `Open` instead of `Add`: `Set objWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Copy _
    After:=objWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.count)
```

here Worksheets.count will refer to the active workbook, but *not in the new instance of Excel you created*. It will instead refer to the active workbook in the instance where your code is running.

Try this:

```
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Copy _
    After:=objWorkbook.Worksheets(objWorkbook.Worksheets.count)
```

You don't need to create a new instance of Excel to do this, and not doing so will prevent this type of easily-overlooked problem.

Comment: as a side note - the reason it may fail is that if you the active workbook had 8 sheets, but the object workbook only had 4, it would try to add the sheet after the 8th sheet, which does not exist in the object workbook.

Comment: This was exactly the issue and fixed my problem. Thanks so much. The reason I created a new instance of Excel is because I am doing much more then just duplicating the sheet (inserting a lot of data from my original workbook to this new one). I just didn't include that code because I have already tested it and it works.